# I get this the error "Error: invalid address ...." while running my dapp

Tags: javascript, blockchain, smartcontracts, quorum

I'm developing a simple dapp for my private blockchain Quorum. I wrote my smart contract in Solidity and a script with JavaScript.

After running my blockchain and my JavaScript console, I did this:

[image]

and I get the error:

> Error: invalid address
>
> at web3.js:3930:15
>
> at web3.js:3756:20
>
> at web3.js:5025:28
>
> at map ( < native code > )
>
> at web3.js:5024:12
>
> at web3.js:5050:18
>
> at web3.js:5075:23
>
> at web3.js:4137:16

My smart contract is this one:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.7.5;

contract MyContract {
    int value;
    
    constructor() public{
        value=10;
    }
      
    function get() public view returns(int) {
        return value;
    }
    
    function set(int value2) public {
        value=value2;
    } 
}
```

And my script in javascript is this one:

```
a = eth.accounts[0]
web3.eth.defaultAccount = a;


// Risultato del comando > solcjs --bin --abi MyContract.sol
var abi = [{"inputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"inputs":[],"name":"get","outputs":[{"internalType":"int256","name":"","type":"int256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"int256","name":"value2","type":"int256"}],"name":"set","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}];

var bytecode = "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";



// Creazione del nuovo contratto con nome MyContract

var simpleContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);

var simple = simpleContract.new({from:web3.eth.accounts[0], data: bytecode, gas: 0x47b760, privateFor: ["QfeDAys9MPDs2XHExtc84jKGHxZg/aj52DTh0vtA3Xc="]}, function(e, contract) {
  if (e) {
    console.log("Error creating contract", e);
  } else {
    if (!contract.address) {
      console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " + contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");
    } else {
      console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);
      console.log(contract);
    }
  }
});
```

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: If you paste the smart contract and script as text instead of an image then it makes it much easier for anyone to try it out to find the issue.

Comment: Yes, it's true!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you have a small mistake in the ABI - the `get()` function should have `"constant":true` in the abi due to the function being labelled as `view`.

Without that, the `get()` function requires a `from` address to be defined for the transaction (i.e. you have to use `private.get({"from": fromAddress})` or set the default account using `web3.eth.defaultAccount = accountAddress`).

If you correct the ABI then it should work.

Comment: I calculate my abi with this command: solcjs --bin --abi MyContract.sol

Is it right?

Comment: Ok, this looks like an incompatibility between the version of solidity compiler you are using and geth. I'm using solcjs version 0.5.0 and I see the `constant` keyword in the abi.
There is more info here: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/8690

I suspect you are using version 0.6* or higher. You can either downgrade your solcj version to 0.5.* or when compiling, specify the target EVM, e.g: 'solcjs --evm-version istanbul --bin --abi MyContract.sol'

Comment: I tried with the command "solcjs --evm-version istanbul --bin --abi MyContract.sol" but the result is the same! :disappointed:
Same error

Comment: Just adding the results from the Slack conversation here: 

The solution is to set the evm-version to `constantinople` when compiling the contract. So the following command fixes it: `solcjs --evm-version constantinople --bin --abi MyContract.sol" `